# Android - facebook automatically post

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I want to integrate an android app with facebook.
I've managed to fetch friends list and to post on wall on demand (a facebook url view is loaded and the user can post on wall whatever he texts).

I want, when the app is started and the user accepts the permisions, to post a message on wall that he is started to play my game without showing that url view for posting (an automatically post)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably late and maybe you've got your answer for this question.
But for anyone else who need an answer:

First, you can use the Graph API, there is an example of how to post on 
a wall. 
**But there is a restriction!!**
Facebook is not allow us to enter a prefiil message! 
The content of this message must come from the user itself!

[Watch this video of Facebook on Platform Policy 2.3 Example and Explanation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill)